# Twitter ruby gem rate limiting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter

I'm building a rails app that uses the Twitter Ruby gem to call the Twitter API. I've authorized the app myself so I get more than the normal 150 (I think I get 350) calls per hour, but in production this still may not be enough. What are my options to avoid rate-limiting besides caching (already doing it) and requiring the user to log in themselves?

Comment: Let users log in and have their own rate limit.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the user **oauth_token** and the user **oauth_token_secret**, and then you do the requests on his behalf (so you don't have the limit).

So, assuming that you have the **token** and **secret_token**, you can do this:

```
@client_twitter = Twitter::Client.new(
      :oauth_token => token,
      :oauth_token_secret => secret_token
    )
```

And just do the request with that @client_twitter. For example:

`@client_twitter.profile_image(uid)`

So, you might be asking: How do I get the oauth_token and oauth_token_secret? They need to give permissions to your app to do so.  You can use [OmniAuth](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth), and you will see both the token and secret token in the hash that is coming back once they have authenticate.